# WPF Button what is the right Trigger for me?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've been trying several properties but I can't seem to get the result I want. Currently, this is what's in my resource dictionary:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="marker" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="marker" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
</Trigger>
```

Now whenever I click one of my buttons (there is 4), the marker object turns black. I move my mouse elsewhere and it's still black - so far so good. Now, however, if I click another control on my application, the button loses focus (naturally) and therefore the marker isn't black anymore!

How can this be prevented? I want the marker to stay black when I click the button and once the button loses focus the marker should still stay black until I click the next button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds more like you're looking for the kind of behaviour you'd get from [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx), where the button is "checked" and "unchecked" by successive clicks.

Try swapping out your Button for a ToggleButton and adding a trigger for the [IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) property rather than the properties you have now.

Comment: Although, having re-read the question, it's not entirely clear what behaviour you do what. ToggleButton may not be the answer. It almost sounds like you want a RadioButton group.

Comment: I'll try using a ToggleButton. The Checked and Unchecked behaviour is what I want.

Comment: I tried the ToggleButton with the trigger "IsChecked". When it's true, the marker should become black, when false it should return to its previous color (red). However I'm unsure how to handle the checking of the button.. this might not be what I need. I think a "isSelected" trigger would be best - but which control would that be?

Comment: Is "marker" not changing back to red when you uncheck the button?

Comment: The question is how do I uncheck the button? My style doesn't allow for a "checkbox". I think however, that this can work if I can somehow add an event that unchecks every other togglebutton, if one of them is checked. Then, I click a button, he gets checked and unchecks all the other togglebuttons - firing their IsChecked=false event and changing them back to the color red. I haven't figured out how to do this, though. I tried EventSetter but that didn't work out.

Comment: @JohnSmith: As suggested earlier you should use [`RadioButtons`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx)...